# PostgreSQL database not connection to android studio

Tags: postgresql, android-studio

```java
public Connection SQLConnection() {
    String ip = "192.168.100.79", port = "5432", dbname = "testdb",
        un = "test_user", pass = "test_password";
    String ConURL;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ConURL = "jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + dbname
                + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + pass;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConURL);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("Error", "PostgreSQL JDBC Driver not found");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "PostgreSQL JDBC Driver not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e("Error",
                "Failed to connect to the database: " + e.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                "Failed to connect to the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    return con;
}
```

Comment: Please give explanation about the problem.

Comment: thank you for help, but this code still not connection to PostgreSQL TT

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Connection con = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btnget = findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText etid = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
    EditText etname = findViewById(R.id.editTextText);
    EditText etuser = findViewById(R.id.editTextText2);
    EditText etpass = findViewById(R.id.editTextText3);

    btnget.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        con = SQLConnection();
        try {
            if (con != null) {
                String Q = "SELECT * FROM loginUser WHERE id = '"+etid.getText().toString()+"';";
                PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(Q);
                st.setString(1, etid.getText().toString());
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    etname.setText(rs.getString(2));
                    etuser.setText(rs.getString(3));
                    etpass.setText(rs.getString(4));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection SQLConnection() {
    String ip = "192.168.100.79", port = "5432", dbname = "loginapp", un = "postgres", pass = "alphaz";
    String ConURL;
    try {

        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        ConURL = "jdbc:postgresql://" + ip + ":" + port + "/" + dbname + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + pass;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(ConURL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", Objects.requireNonNull(e.getMessage()));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "データベースに接続できません。", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return con;
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).